# How to access a List objects in an ASP.Net web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new in ASP.Net and MVC5 programming,in fact I have a problem,I have this Class "Student":

```
namespace Project.Entities.Models
{
    public partial class Student : BaseEntity
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ClassId")]
        public virtual Class Class { get; set; }
        public Int64 ClassId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ImageId")]
        public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
        public Int64 ImageId { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Mark> Marks { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Punishment> Punishments { get; set; }


        public Student()
        {
            Marks = new List<Mark>();
            Punishments = new List<Punishment>();
        }
    }
```

Class "Mark":

```
namespace SMA.Entities.Models
{
    public partial class Mark : BaseEntity
    {
        public int Score { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("StudentId")]
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
        public Int64 StudentId { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I want to get the Marks of each Student,but I don't know How,
this is what I get in JSON result:

```
[
{
FirstName: "Student ",
LastName: "1",
Class: null,
ClassId: 1,
Image: null,
ImageId: 1,
Marks: [ ],
Punishments: [ ],
Id: 1,
ObjectState: 0
},
{
FirstName: "Student ",
LastName: "2",
Class: null,
ClassId: 2,
Image: null,
ImageId: 2,
Marks: [ ],
Punishments: [ ],
Id: 2,
ObjectState: 0
}
]
```

so please,have you any idea about,how can I access the Marks data for each Student
thanks for help

Comment: Please add you controller code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have an Id field in your Student entity that is the primary key (you didn't show it in the question, but I assume it was omitted), try changing this:

```
public virtual List<Mark> Marks { get; set; }
public virtual List<Punishment> Punishments { get; set; }
```

to

```
public virtual ICollection<Mark> Marks { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Punishment> Punishments { get; set; }
```